# Firefox Addon SDK - pageMod update contentScriptOptions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am adding content scripts to pages on `example.com` using the following code in my `main.js`:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
        include: "https://example.com/*",
        contentScriptWhen: "ready",
        contentScriptFile: [
            self.data.url("example.js"),
        ],
        contentScriptOptions: {
            myString: 'helloWorld'
        }
    });
```

If I set up a worker or event listener that tells `main.js` to update the value of `myString` (accessible from the content script using `self.options.myString`), how can I reflect that change in the `example.js` content script for the next `example.com` page load?

I've tried calling the `pageMod.PageMod` function again with the new `myString` value, but that causes `example.js` to run twice on pages.

**Edit:**

I've implemented the [Port API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on), but now I'm stuck on how to update the object that `contentScriptOptions` passes to the content scripts.

```
/* main.js */
var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://example.com/*",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: [
        self.data.url("example.js"),
    ],
    contentScriptOptions: {
        myString: 'foo'
    },
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("updateOptions", function(data) {

            // how to replace myString with value from data.myString?

        });
    }
});
```

and

```
/* example.js */
self.port.emit('updateOptions', { myString: 'bar' });
```

Comment: Note that the object you pass as `contentScriptOptions` cannot contain any functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Port API.

In your content script, `emit` the message that a listening PageMod will receive.

```
/* example.js */  
self.port.emit("nameForTheMessage", "bar"); // self is a global variable
```

In the PageMod, invoke a function `onAttach` of the content script.

```
/* main.js */
var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

var externalStringVar =  "helloWorld";

var pageMod = pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://example.com/*",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("example.js")],
    contentScriptOptions: {
        myString: externalStrVar; // Pass it to the content script
    }
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("nameForTheMessage", function(updatedString) {
            // update string value when a message is received like so:
            externalStringVar = updatedString;
        });
    }
});
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on)

Comment: I tried this, but the `myString` in the `worker.port.on` function does not refer to the same `myString` as in the `contentScriptOptions` that gets passed to the content scripts. It doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I've got so far.

Comment: @iglvzx I've updated my answer too (note that both files have changes).

Comment: Now the myString data is not passed to the content script.

Comment: @iglvzx My apologies for misunderstanding. The new edit with `contentScriptOptions` included should help you achieve what you are looking for in the simplest sense. Or did you mean updating the value of `myString` inside `contentScriptOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

Updates to options do not propagate to already-loaded workers. You will have to use message-passing through the [port API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on) to communicate with the content script.